# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [Eclipse, Tomcat]

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I know that's an over-asked question, but still I can't get this thing right.
I'm running a web application on Eclipse who has to interact with a mysql database. It all runs on a tomcat 7.0.27 server on localhost.

As much as I try to add my my mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar to java build path, i still get the same error. Apparently it doesn't matter if I put it as an external lib or inside my Webcontent/META-INF/lib folder. Also tried different version of the connector (18 and 25).

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at 
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at ns.Data.getInfo(Data.java:36)
>       at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:78)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

this is the class that calls the driver:

```
    package ns;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Data { 

    public Data() {

    };

    public int prova = 4;

    {

    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + "127.0.0.1" + "/" + "test" + "?" + "user=" + "matt" + "&password=" + "pass"); 
        Statement cmd = con.createStatement();

 // TODO QUERY
        ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM carshare.passaggi");


        con.close(); } 
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Errore con DB o Query errata"); 
    e.printStackTrace(); }


}

    public String[] getInfo(String table, String column) {
        String[] values = new String[100];
        int i = 0;
        String temp;

        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + "127.0.0.1" + "/" + "test" + "?" + "user=" + "matt" + "&password=" + "pass"); 
            Statement cmd = con.createStatement();

     // QUERY DA ESEGUIRE 
            ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM carshare."+ table);
        /*              
            while (rs.next()==true) {
                temp = rs.getString(column);
                System.out.print(temp);
                values[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
            */
            con.close(); } 
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Errore con DB o Query errata"); 
        e.printStackTrace(); }      


        return values;
    }

}
```

I'll welcome any advice or suggestion and will require additional info if needed.

Comment: it should be in your Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib folder not Webcontent/META-INF/lib

Comment: FFS, i've looked into this for hours and I couldn't realize that I had picked the wrong folder. Feels quite dumb. You have all my thanks, anyway. I can finally start working now.

Comment: I'm going to put this as an answer so you can mark it as correct and close it off as answered ok

Comment: Allright, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in your Webcontent/**WEB-INF**/lib folder *not* Webcontent/**META-INF**/lib